# Let $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^+$ Prove that $\Bigr(1+\frac{1}{x}\Bigl)\Bigr(1+\frac{1}{y}\Bigl)\ge \Bigr(1+\frac{2}{x+y}\Bigl)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, factoring, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^+$ Prove that $$\Bigr(1+\frac{1}{x}\Bigl)\Bigr(1+\frac{1}{y}\Bigl)\ge \Bigr(1+\frac{2}{x+y}\Bigl)^2$$

**My try**

Well, i didn't see a way to factorize this, so i put it in WolframAlpha and i got that we can rewrite it like this, which is obviously true for $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^+$:

$$\frac{(y-x)^2(x+y+1)}{xy(x+y)^2}\ge 0$$

But i don't see the way to get there manually, im stuck here:

$$\frac{(x+y)(y+1)}{xy}\ge \frac{(x+y+2)^2}{(x+y)^2}$$

Comment: At an elementary level the best way to handle inequalities like this is to multiply it all by a common denominator and then expand everything and subtract the RHS from both sides ans then simplify. Then see whether some parts can be re-factored to yield a formula that's never negative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $a=1/x>0$ and $b=1/y>0$. So we have to prove $$(1+a)(1+b)\geq (1+{2ab\over a+b})^2$$
or $$(a+b)^3+ab (a+b)^2\geq 4ab(a+b)+ 4a^2b^2$$
or $$(a+b)^2(a+b+ab)\geq 4ab(a+b+ ab)$$
or (since $a+b+ab>0$) $$(a+b)^2\geq 4ab$$ which is true.

Comment: That is pretty smart.

Comment: Substitution $a=\frac{1}{x}$ is often a good approach when inequality contains a lot of terms like $\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 4):

It is equivalent to
$$ \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right) \geq \log\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+y}{2}}\right) $$
i.e. to the midpoint-convexity of $f(z)=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$. It simply follows from convexity, and convexity is a consequence of $f''(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}>0$.

Answer (score 4):

It's just Jensen for $f(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

Indeed, $f''(x)=\frac{(2x+1)}{x^2(x+1)^2}>0$ and we get
$$\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{2}\geq\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+y}{2}}\right),$$
which is your inequality.

Also, it's
$$1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{xy}\geq1+\frac{4}{x+y}+\frac{4}{(x+y)^2},$$ which is true by C-S
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\geq\frac{(1+1)^2}{x+y}=\frac{4}{x+y}$$ and AM-GM
$$\frac{1}{xy}\geq\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{4}{(x+y)^2}.$$

Comment: is it true that for $x>0,y>0,z>0$ is hold: $$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)\geq \left(1+\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^2$$?

Comment: +1 though it's tagged as ([tag:algebra-precalculus]).

Comment: Even $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)\geq\left(1+\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^3$ is true.

Comment: thank you Michael for your quick response, ok i will try it

Answer (score 3):

it is just $AM-GM$
multiplying out we get
$$(x+y)^2+\frac{(x+y)^2}{x}+\frac{(x+y)^2}{y}+\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}\geq (x+y)^2+4+4(x+y)$$ and this is
$$xy(x+y)^2+y(x+y)^2+x(x+y)^2+(x+y)^2\geq xy(x+y)^2+4xy+4xy(x+y)$$
$$(x+y)^3+(x+y)^2\geq 4xy+4xy(x+y)$$
and this is $$(x+y)^2(x+y+1)\geq 4xy(x+y+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

Why did nobody mention the one-liner solution:

$$\left(1+\frac 1x\right)\left(1+\frac 1y\right)\stackrel{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}\geq\left(1+\frac {1}{\sqrt{xy}}\right)^2\stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}\geq\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+y}{2}}\right)^2 = \left(1+\frac{2}{x+y}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb R^+×\mathbb R^+$ is convex, and the problem is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, the minimum of $$(1+\frac1x)(1+\frac1y)-(1+\frac2{x+y})^2 $$ occurs when $x=y$...

If $x=y$ we get $$(1+\frac1x)(1+\frac1x)-(1+\frac2{2x})^2=0$$...

It's a minimum since for instance  $(1,2)$ gives $3-\frac53=\frac43\gt 0$...

Comment: As I understand it, you can only state that there is a local extremum at $x=y$, but that need not be a *global* one. Essentially the same point as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2600784/42969.

Comment: Yes, i should probably stop using the argument until I can understand it better.  I was reading about it here, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58721/when-does-symmetry-in-an-optimization-problem-imply-that-all-variables-are-equal but honestly still haven't seen the proof all the way through. ..  it is an interesting phenomenon though...

Comment: Same problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2647104/42969.

Comment: Yes.  I was just going to ask you what you thought of that.  So you don't think the convexity condition is enough?  For instance,  i couldn't do this if the region was a sphere (not convex)...  it's not a proof, but I was encouraged by the realization that this type of problem would be filtered out, as I came across one such, where it didn't work...

Comment: Evidently it's called the Purkiss principle...

Comment: Then this would be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/683668/42969: *"The main problem with the Purkiss Principle, most of the time, is to prove that the extreme found is global."*

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:$$\left (\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right )^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

I give a proof using Cauchy-Schwartz for fun.

$$\Bigr(1+\frac{1}{x}\Bigl)\Bigr(1+\frac{1}{y}\Bigl)\ge \Bigr(1+\frac{2}{x+y}\Bigl)^2$$
$$\iff \Bigr((x+y)(1+\frac{1}{x})\Bigl)\Bigr((x+y)(1+\frac{1}{y})\Bigl)\ge \Bigr(x+y+2\Bigl)^2$$
$$\iff \Bigr(x+y+1+\frac{y}{x}\Bigl) \Bigr(x+y+1+\frac{x}{y}\Bigl) \ge \Bigr(x+y+2\Bigl)^2$$
$$\iff \Bigr(\sqrt x^2+\sqrt y^2+1^2+\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}^2\Bigl) \Bigr(\sqrt x^2+\sqrt y^2+1^2+\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}^2\Bigl) \\
\ge (\sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x + \sqrt y \cdot \sqrt y + 1\cdot1 + \sqrt{\frac{y}{x}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}})^2 $$